# Video inside svg is not shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

The video is not shown inside svg and i'm using `foreignObject`. But when i add `autoplay` tag to it does gets autoplayed i do hear the audio but there is no video.What is the problem here?

here's the part with video:

```
...
<rect
                width="510.757"
                height="316.027"
                transform="translate(427.919 928.655)"
                fill="url(#k)"
              >
                <foreignObject
                  x="427.919"
                  y="928.655"
                  width="510.76"
                  height="316.3"
                >
                  <video
                    controls
                    width="510.76"
                    height="316.3"
                    className="media-area-video img-fluid"
                  >
                    <source
                      src="https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"
                      type="video/webm"
                    />
                  </video>
                </foreignObject>
              </rect>
...
```

**the full content of svg**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="663.221"
            height="376.367"
            className="img-fluid"
            viewBox="0 0 663.221 376.367"
          >
            <defs>
              <linearGradient
                id="a"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9a9a9a" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#a2a2a2" />
                <stop offset="0.24" stop-color="#b8b8b8" />
                <stop offset="0.42" stop-color="#dbdbdb" />
                <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#e2e2e2" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c5" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="b"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#404040" />
                <stop offset="0.28" stop-color="#434343" />
                <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#4b4b4b" />
                <stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#595959" />
                <stop offset="0.71" stop-color="#6d6d6d" />
                <stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#888" />
                <stop offset="0.92" stop-color="#a7a7a7" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c5" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="c"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#929292" />
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#c1c1c1" />
                <stop offset="0.03" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#9c9c9c" />
                <stop offset="0.07" stop-color="#a4a4a4" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#afafaf" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#cfcfcf" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="d"
                y1="0.508"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.508"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="0.06" stop-color="#d0d0d0" />
                <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="0.87" stop-color="#d0d0d0" />
                <stop offset="0.88" stop-color="#d3d3d3" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#e9e9e9" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="e"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#cfcfcf" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#afafaf" />
                <stop offset="0.93" stop-color="#a4a4a4" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#9c9c9c" />
                <stop offset="0.97" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.99" stop-color="#c1c1c1" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#929292" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="f"
                y1="0.501"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.501"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#666" />
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
                <stop offset="0.02" stop-color="#bdbdbd" />
                <stop offset="0.04" stop-color="#868686" />
                <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#707070" />
                <stop offset="0.06" stop-color="#787878" />
                <stop offset="0.07" stop-color="#8e8e8e" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#bcbcbc" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="g"
                y1="0.501"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.501"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#bcbcbc" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.93" stop-color="#8e8e8e" />
                <stop offset="0.94" stop-color="#787878" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#707070" />
                <stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#868686" />
                <stop offset="0.98" stop-color="#bdbdbd" />
                <stop offset="0.99" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#666" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="h"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
                <stop offset="0.04" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="0.51" stop-color="#e5e5e5" />
                <stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="i"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7" />
                <stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f7f7f7" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="j"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#575757" />
                <stop offset="0.74" stop-color="#b9b9b9" />
                <stop offset="0.85" stop-color="#b6b6b6" />
                <stop offset="0.94" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="k"
                x1="0.095"
                y1="-0.154"
                x2="0.905"
                y2="1.154"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f2f3f4" />
                <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#edeeef" />
                <stop offset="0.78" stop-color="#dfe0e0" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d5d6d6" />
              </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <g transform="translate(-349 -906.187)">
              <path
                d="M695.419,267.93H190.624a16.269,16.269,0,0,0-16.334,16.155V621.739h2.344V281.773a13.725,13.725,0,0,1,.155-2.1,3.809,3.809,0,0,1,.122-.678,6.664,6.664,0,0,1,.163-.67c.065-.221.114-.441.188-.653a13.721,13.721,0,0,1,2.785-4.9,6.528,6.528,0,0,1,.457-.49l.229-.237a14.154,14.154,0,0,1,2.36-1.87c.286-.18.572-.351.874-.515s.6-.3.907-.441h0l.629-.253h0a14.268,14.268,0,0,1,5.129-.956H695.386a14.1,14.1,0,0,1,6.672,1.634c.294.163.588.335.874.514s.743.5,1.095.768h0l.514.425h0c.253.22.5.441.735.678l.237.237c.155.155.31.319.457.49a13.647,13.647,0,0,1,3.414,9.033V621.739h2.377V283.072A16.286,16.286,0,0,0,695.419,267.93Z"
                transform="translate(240.308 640.569)"
                fill="url(#a)"
              />
              <path
                d="M174.2,281.254A16.269,16.269,0,0,1,190.575,265.1H695.37a16.269,16.269,0,0,1,16.383,16.155v1.3a16.285,16.285,0,0,0-16.334-15.142h-504.8a16.269,16.269,0,0,0-16.383,16.155Z"
                transform="translate(240.325 641.087)"
                fill="url(#b)"
              />
              <rect
                width="532.808"
                height="9.458"
                transform="translate(416.893 1252.858)"
              />
              <path
                d="M709.908,281.884V612.3H177.1V281.884A13.966,13.966,0,0,1,191.107,268H695.9a13.966,13.966,0,0,1,14.007,13.884Z"
                transform="translate(239.793 640.556)"
              />
              <path
                d="M617.78,436.04v.866H80.26v-.866Z"
                transform="translate(334.29 826.268)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="10.037"
                transform="translate(349 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#c)"
              />
              <rect
                width="663.212"
                height="0.498"
                transform="translate(349 1263.173)"
                fill="url(#d)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="10.037"
                transform="translate(680.61 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#e)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="9.441"
                transform="translate(349 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#f)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="9.441"
                transform="translate(680.61 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#g)"
              />
              <path
                d="M536.606,702.2a7.694,7.694,0,0,1-7.685,7.694H449.887a7.685,7.685,0,0,1-7.677-7.694Z"
                transform="translate(191.203 560.973)"
                fill="url(#h)"
              />
              <g transform="translate(633.037 1263.173)">
                <path
                  d="M536.53,702.2a7.693,7.693,0,0,1-7.693,7.694H449.811a7.685,7.685,0,0,1-7.685-7.694h-.376v.58a7.685,7.685,0,0,0,7.685,7.677h79.777a7.677,7.677,0,0,0,7.685-7.677v-.58Z"
                  transform="translate(-441.75 -702.2)"
                  fill="url(#i)"
                />
              </g>
              <path
                d="M94,715.1a295.949,295.949,0,0,0,72.034,8.845H685.162a295.959,295.959,0,0,0,72.01-8.845Z"
                transform="translate(255.025 558.609)"
                fill="url(#j)"
              />
              <rect
                width="510.757"
                height="316.027"
                transform="translate(427.919 928.655)"
                fill="url(#k)"
              >
                <foreignObject
                  x="427.919"
                  y="928.655"
                  width="510.76"
                  height="316.3"
                >
                  <video
                    controls
                    width="510.76"
                    height="316.3"
                    className="media-area-video img-fluid"
                  >
                    <source
                      src="https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"
                      type="video/webm"
                    />
                  </video>
                </foreignObject>
              </rect>
            </g>
          </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

The svg must be placed on the monitor of laptop svg.

Edit:
the link to github repo: https://github.com/amir-mln/so-svg

Comment: This post might describe a similar issue and be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324916/video-tag-embedded-in-svg

Comment: thanks, but i had seen that issue, but i did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the nesting of the `<foreignObject>` element inside of the `<rect>`.

The solution is to create a new group (`<g>`) around the rect and make the `foreignObject` a sibling of rect instead of a child of rect. The group should have `transform` value of the `<rect>`.

Then set the `x` and `y` attributes of the `foreignObject` to `0`.

```
<g transform="translate(427.919 928.655)">
  <rect
    width="510.757"
    height="316.027"
    fill="url(#k)"
  />
  <foreignObject
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="510.76"
    height="316.3"
  >
    <video>
    ...
    </video>
  </foreignObject>
</g>
```

See it in action:

```css
.media-area-video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="663.221"
            height="376.367"
            className="img-fluid"
            viewBox="0 0 663.221 376.367"
          >
            <defs>
              <linearGradient
                id="a"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9a9a9a" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#a2a2a2" />
                <stop offset="0.24" stop-color="#b8b8b8" />
                <stop offset="0.42" stop-color="#dbdbdb" />
                <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#e2e2e2" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c5" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="b"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#404040" />
                <stop offset="0.28" stop-color="#434343" />
                <stop offset="0.45" stop-color="#4b4b4b" />
                <stop offset="0.59" stop-color="#595959" />
                <stop offset="0.71" stop-color="#6d6d6d" />
                <stop offset="0.82" stop-color="#888" />
                <stop offset="0.92" stop-color="#a7a7a7" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#c5c5c5" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="c"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#929292" />
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#c1c1c1" />
                <stop offset="0.03" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#9c9c9c" />
                <stop offset="0.07" stop-color="#a4a4a4" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#afafaf" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#cfcfcf" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="d"
                y1="0.508"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.508"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="0.06" stop-color="#d0d0d0" />
                <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="0.87" stop-color="#d0d0d0" />
                <stop offset="0.88" stop-color="#d3d3d3" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#e9e9e9" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="e"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#cfcfcf" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#afafaf" />
                <stop offset="0.93" stop-color="#a4a4a4" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#9c9c9c" />
                <stop offset="0.97" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.99" stop-color="#c1c1c1" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#929292" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="f"
                y1="0.501"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.501"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#666" />
                <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
                <stop offset="0.02" stop-color="#bdbdbd" />
                <stop offset="0.04" stop-color="#868686" />
                <stop offset="0.05" stop-color="#707070" />
                <stop offset="0.06" stop-color="#787878" />
                <stop offset="0.07" stop-color="#8e8e8e" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.09" stop-color="#bcbcbc" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="g"
                y1="0.501"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.501"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f1f1f1" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#bcbcbc" />
                <stop offset="0.91" stop-color="#b2b2b2" />
                <stop offset="0.93" stop-color="#8e8e8e" />
                <stop offset="0.94" stop-color="#787878" />
                <stop offset="0.95" stop-color="#707070" />
                <stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#868686" />
                <stop offset="0.98" stop-color="#bdbdbd" />
                <stop offset="0.99" stop-color="#d5d5d5" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#666" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="h"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
                <stop offset="0.04" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="0.51" stop-color="#e5e5e5" />
                <stop offset="0.96" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="i"
                y1="0.5"
                x2="1"
                y2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f7f7f7" />
                <stop offset="0.52" stop-color="#f8f8f8" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f7f7f7" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="j"
                x1="0.5"
                y1="1"
                x2="0.5"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#575757" />
                <stop offset="0.74" stop-color="#b9b9b9" />
                <stop offset="0.85" stop-color="#b6b6b6" />
                <stop offset="0.94" stop-color="#acacac" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9f9f9f" />
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient
                id="k"
                x1="0.095"
                y1="-0.154"
                x2="0.905"
                y2="1.154"
                gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              >
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f2f3f4" />
                <stop offset="0.36" stop-color="#edeeef" />
                <stop offset="0.78" stop-color="#dfe0e0" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d5d6d6" />
              </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <g transform="translate(-349 -906.187)">
              <path
                d="M695.419,267.93H190.624a16.269,16.269,0,0,0-16.334,16.155V621.739h2.344V281.773a13.725,13.725,0,0,1,.155-2.1,3.809,3.809,0,0,1,.122-.678,6.664,6.664,0,0,1,.163-.67c.065-.221.114-.441.188-.653a13.721,13.721,0,0,1,2.785-4.9,6.528,6.528,0,0,1,.457-.49l.229-.237a14.154,14.154,0,0,1,2.36-1.87c.286-.18.572-.351.874-.515s.6-.3.907-.441h0l.629-.253h0a14.268,14.268,0,0,1,5.129-.956H695.386a14.1,14.1,0,0,1,6.672,1.634c.294.163.588.335.874.514s.743.5,1.095.768h0l.514.425h0c.253.22.5.441.735.678l.237.237c.155.155.31.319.457.49a13.647,13.647,0,0,1,3.414,9.033V621.739h2.377V283.072A16.286,16.286,0,0,0,695.419,267.93Z"
                transform="translate(240.308 640.569)"
                fill="url(#a)"
              />
              <path
                d="M174.2,281.254A16.269,16.269,0,0,1,190.575,265.1H695.37a16.269,16.269,0,0,1,16.383,16.155v1.3a16.285,16.285,0,0,0-16.334-15.142h-504.8a16.269,16.269,0,0,0-16.383,16.155Z"
                transform="translate(240.325 641.087)"
                fill="url(#b)"
              />
              <rect
                width="532.808"
                height="9.458"
                transform="translate(416.893 1252.858)"
              />
              <path
                d="M709.908,281.884V612.3H177.1V281.884A13.966,13.966,0,0,1,191.107,268H695.9a13.966,13.966,0,0,1,14.007,13.884Z"
                transform="translate(239.793 640.556)"
              />
              <path
                d="M617.78,436.04v.866H80.26v-.866Z"
                transform="translate(334.29 826.268)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="10.037"
                transform="translate(349 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#c)"
              />
              <rect
                width="663.212"
                height="0.498"
                transform="translate(349 1263.173)"
                fill="url(#d)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="10.037"
                transform="translate(680.61 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#e)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="9.441"
                transform="translate(349 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#f)"
              />
              <rect
                width="331.61"
                height="9.441"
                transform="translate(680.61 1263.671)"
                fill="url(#g)"
              />
              <path
                d="M536.606,702.2a7.694,7.694,0,0,1-7.685,7.694H449.887a7.685,7.685,0,0,1-7.677-7.694Z"
                transform="translate(191.203 560.973)"
                fill="url(#h)"
              />
              <g transform="translate(633.037 1263.173)">
                <path
                  d="M536.53,702.2a7.693,7.693,0,0,1-7.693,7.694H449.811a7.685,7.685,0,0,1-7.685-7.694h-.376v.58a7.685,7.685,0,0,0,7.685,7.677h79.777a7.677,7.677,0,0,0,7.685-7.677v-.58Z"
                  transform="translate(-441.75 -702.2)"
                  fill="url(#i)"
                />
              </g>
              <path
                d="M94,715.1a295.949,295.949,0,0,0,72.034,8.845H685.162a295.959,295.959,0,0,0,72.01-8.845Z"
                transform="translate(255.025 558.609)"
                fill="url(#j)"
              />
              <g transform="translate(427.919 928.655)">
              <rect
                width="510.757"
                height="316.027"
                fill="url(#k)"
              />
              <foreignObject
                x="0"
                y="0"
                width="510.76"
                height="316.3"
              >
                <video
                  controls
                  width="510.76"
                  height="316.3"
                  class="media-area-video img-fluid"
                >
                  <source
                    src="https://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm"
                    type="video/webm"
                  />
                </video>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
            </g>
          </svg>
</body>
</html>
```