# Is there any way to add watermark on html5/html 5 video element, which user can not remove by going into the browser console/inspect mode?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, watermark

I want to create a video watermark, which end user can not remove by manipulating DOM.
Currently I tried adding watermark by using css and overlays, which is pretty easy to remove if user has even a little knowledge about DOM and browser elements.

Comment: No. If it comes to the browser unmarked, then user can get access to this unmarked media. Do the marking server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one trick, but this is just a theory - instead of displaying all images directly, create an SVG wrapper that will be displaying actual video, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324916/video-tag-embedded-in-svg).

Then on your main page, display this SVG control using `img` or `iframe`.

**Sample.svg**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <text x="0" y="0">Some watermark goes here</text>
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="300" height="100">
    <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="300" height="100">
      <source src="some-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

**Main page**

```
<img src="sample.svg" />
```